# Jogging in Bucharest?

Tags: romania, parks-and-gardens, bucharest

In Bucharest, which parks or areas are appropriate or well known for jogging?

When I'm at home in London, I prefer not to Jog through the streets because of the need to cross roads and avoid traffic, also inhaling the exhaust fumes from road vehicles is not nice. So I'm accustomed to running around parks, but I am willing to run on the streets if I can avoid having to cross the road.

Is there a place in Bucharest known for jogging that I could go to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous parks in Bucharest which are of course paradise for joggers and runners. You can find more information and useful descriptions [on the official city website, under `Culture/Leisure -> Parks and Gardens`](http://www1.pmb.ro/pmb/index_en.htm). [Searching for `bucharest jogging` on google](https://www.google.fr/search?q=bucharest%20jogging&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=MKBlVa7HIcTtUsqxgLgN) reveals that the web is scattered with jogging trail maps for Bucharest. Some, if not most, of which are enclosed in one of the many parks in the city. [Here is a list of numerous trails on Map My Run.](http://www.mapmyrun.com/ro/bucharest-bucuresti/) Picking one at random yields [this trail in the Herastrau Park](http://www.mapmyrun.com/ro/bucharest-bucuresti/8-80km-run-on-11-2-12-route-150612043), the largest in Bucharest. You can of course pick a park at random and design your own route.